# How can I remove a single route in test environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, tdd

So, I've a test where I create an action on a controller to test certain thing. To do this I added the action on my controller and create a route for my action as follows:

```rb
before do
    test_routes = Proc.new do
        get    'mocked_action', to: 'custom_controller#mocked_action',  as: :mocked_action
    end
    MyApp::Application.routes.send :eval_block, test_routes
end
```

Well, how do I remove this route in specific?

```rb
after do
    #Remove my temp route here
end
```

Comment: Can you describe the actual problem you are trying to solve? Why do you need to invoke whatever behaviour you are testing via HTTP?

Comment: I have a module for permissions to users, and to test this module I'm creating a fictitious controller and including this module. I need to test if a user doesn't have permission to certain functionality it can't access.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch setting up the temporary routes by using dynamic contraints: http://raysrashmi.com/2014/07/23/rails-routes-constraints/

Enabling and disabling through before and after hooks can be done by setting flags etc.
In general I wonder if your test setup should be done this way. In my opinion depending on a user role would be more straight forward.